# segfault using numpy's lapack_lite with multiprocessing on osx, not linux

Tags: python, numpy, segmentation-fault, multiprocessing

The following test code segfaults for me on OSX 10.7.3, but not other machines:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import scipy.linalg

def f(a):
    print("about to call")

    ### these all cause crashes
    sign, x = np.linalg.slogdet(a)
    #x = np.linalg.det(a)
    #x = np.linalg.inv(a).sum()

    ### these are all fine
    #x = scipy.linalg.expm3(a).sum()
    #x = np.dot(a, a.T).sum()

    print("result:", x)
    return x

def call_proc(a):
    print("\ncalling with multiprocessing")
    p = mp.Process(target=f, args=(a,))
    p.start()
    p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    n = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 50

    a = np.random.normal(0, 2, (n, n))
    f(a)

    call_proc(a)
    call_proc(a)
```

Example output for one of the segfaulty ones:

```
$ python2.7 test.py
about to call
result: -4.96797718087

calling with multiprocessing
about to call

calling with multiprocessing
about to call
```

with an OSX "problem report" popping up complaining about a segfault like `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000108`; [here's a full one](https://gist.github.com/2209271).

If I run it with `n <= 32`, it runs fine; for any `n >= 33`, it crashes.

If I comment out the `f(a)` call that's done in the original process, both calls to `call_proc` are fine. It still segfaults if I call `f` on a different large array; if I call it on a different small array, or if I call `f(large_array)` and then pass off `f(small_array)` to a different process, it works fine. They don't actually need to be the same function; `np.inv(large_array)` followed by passing off to `np.linalg.slogdet(different_large_array)` also segfaults.

All of the commented-out `np.linalg` things in `f` cause crashes; `np.dot(self.a, self.a.T).sum()` and `scipy.linalg.exp3m` work fine. As far as I can tell, the difference is that the former use numpy's lapack_lite and the latter don't.

---

This happens for me on my desktop with

- python 2.6.7, numpy 1.5.1
- python 2.7.1, numpy 1.5.1, scipy 0.10.0
- python 3.2.2, numpy 1.6.1, scipy 0.10.1

The 2.6 and 2.7 are I think the default system installs; I installed the 3.2 versions manually from the source tarballs. All of those numpys are linked to the system Accelerate framework:

```
$ otool -L `python3.2 -c 'from numpy.core import _dotblas; print(_dotblas.__file__)'`
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/core/_dotblas.so:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.1)
```

I get the same behavior on another Mac with a similar setup.

But all of the options for `f` work on other machines running

- OSX 10.6.8 with Python 2.6.1 and numpy 1.2.1 linked to Accelerate 4 and vecLib 268 (except that it doesn't have scipy or `slogdet`)
- Debian 6 with Python 3.2.2, numpy 1.6.1, and scipy 0.10.1 linked to the system ATLAS
- Ubuntu 11.04 with Python 2.7.1, numpy 1.5.1 and scipy 0.8.0 linked to system ATLAS

---

Am I doing something wrong here? What could possibly be causing this? I don't see how running a function on a numpy array that's getting pickled and unpickled can possibly cause it to later segfault in a different process.

---

**Update:** when I do a core dump, the backtrace is inside `dispatch_group_async_f`, the Grand Central Dispatch interface. Presumably this is a bug in the interactions between numpy/GCD and multiprocessing. I`ve reported this as [a numpy bug](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/2091), but if anyone has any ideas about workarounds or, for that matter, how to solve the bug, it'd be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: As a mature library, numpy *should* never cause a segmentation fault or otherwise abort the current process. Have you submitted a bug report at http://projects.scipy.org/numpy ?

Comment: Yep, I reported it: http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/2091. The ticket has seen absolutely zero response, though, and I just stopped running that code on OSX. I'll re-test on 10.8 with numpy master and post an update next week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the Accelerate framework used by default on OSX [just doesn't support using BLAS calls on both sides of a `fork`](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2012-August/063589.html). No real way to deal with this other than linking to a different BLAS, and it doesn't seem like something they're interested in fixing.

Comment: In Python 3.4 there will be `forkserver` mode for multiprocessing that should make it possible to use Accelerate or OpenBLAS with multiprocessing.

Comment: @ogrisel's comment should be the answer. Worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 1):

As per @ogrisel's comment, I tried calling `multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver')` before using `multiprocessing.Pool` and it worked like a charm!