# Installing numpy on Mac OS X Mavericks with alternate LAPACK/BLAS

Tags: python, macos, numpy, lapack

I'm trying to parallelize some Python code that uses NumPy extensively with the Python multiprocessing package. Unfortunately, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705200/multiprocessing-with-numpy-makes-python-quit-unexpectedly-on-osx), the default linear algebra libraries provided by Apple (Accelerate/Veclib) cannot be run in parallel. So I'm trying to link an alternate LAPACK/BLAS when installing NumPy, in the hopes that my code can then be parallelized without crashes!

I downloaded and compiled an alternative LAPACK/BLAS. Then, following instructions [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html), I did:

```
export LAPACK=/usr/local/Cellar/lapack/3.4.2/lib/liblapack.dylib
export BLAS=/usr/local/Cellar/lapack/3.4.2/lib/libblas.dylib
export ATLAS=None
pip install numpy
```

which ran fine. However, if I run

```
numpy.show_config()
```

in Python, I get

```
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

indicating NumPy is still using Apple's LAPACK/BLAS! And indeed crashes still abound. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have either of the Fortran compilers, g77 or gfortran installed? I do not and see pretty much the same as what you are seeing - installed using Anaconda.

Comment: Yes, I have gfortran installed.

Comment: To correct you slightly, the default linear algebra libraries provided by Apple "run in parallel" just fine; the problem is with calling them on both sides of a fork-without-exec (and I should note that there's no really good reason to expect that *would* work).

Comment: These instructions worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14391693/777706

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if either of these will be any help:
https://github.com/obspy/obspy/wiki/Notes-on-Parallel-Processing-with-Python-and-ObsPy

[Multiprocessing with numpy makes Python quit unexpectedly on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705200/multiprocessing-with-numpy-makes-python-quit-unexpectedly-on-osx)

I remember seeing something about lapack/blas on a Mac forum as well, but have not located it, but the author seemed to know what she was talking about.

Comment: Thanks, that helped point me to the right answer, which was to install OpenBLAS and manually edit the site.cfg file while installing NumPy (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443302/compiling-numpy-with-openblas-integration)).