# ndarray.dot() function hangs in exec

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I have a problem to run *ndarray.dot(array-like object)* either in Python 2.7 and 3.4 in *exec()* function - python hangs and I need to close it. Based on [Numpy "dot" hangs](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5752) or [multiprocessing with numpy quits Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705200/multiprocessing-with-numpy-makes-python-quit-unexpectedly-on-osx) it is a known issue. When multiprocessing library is used, python hangs because of the deadlock.

How the code below behaves using *exec()*? Does *exec()* create a new thread? Is there any solution to fix it?

The actual code is more complex, so I need to use exec().

**test_dot.py:**

```
test_global_env = {
    '__builtins__': None,
    'np': numpy
}
test_local_env = {}
test = '''
result = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]).dot([0.14, 0.1])
'''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    exec(test, test_global_env, test_local_env)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably problem with line `'__builtins__': None,`. If you comment this line out, your code will work just fine. Btw. what was the purpose of this line?

`exec` does not create another thread, it executes in the current thread and any other function. The rest of the code simply waits for `exec` to be finished before is continues.

Comment: Great, you are right. Since I am creating a "IDE"/"sandbox" to run miscellaneous python code, I can't allow the user to use every function or class from builtins. I want to allow only functions like min, max, tuple, dict, range, iter, isinstance, enumerate, iter. But don't want to allow __import__.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if everything will work, what if the code you call will need some import in background in order to run (I mean what if for example `np.dot()` imports something)?